# How to surround JSON values with characters using sed

Tags: json, regex, sed

I would like to do append some characters to JSON values using sed.
For example given:

```
{"contactForm":{"title":"Mr","firstName":"Jimmy","phonenumber":"12341234"}}
```

I want to transform into:

```
{"contactForm":{"title":"_Mr_","firstName":"_Jimmy_","phonenumber":"_12341234_"}}
```

Note the values only are surrounded by underscores.

Using this expression *almost* results in the right matches (apart from matching curly braces at the end):

```
[^:]+(?=,|$)
```

See example at: 
https://regex101.com/r/nE5eV3/409

But I can't get sed to even print the capture as a starting point:

```
sed 's/[^:]+(?=,|$)/\\1/'
{"contactForm":{"title":"Mr","firstName":"Jimmy","phonenumber":"12341234"}}
{"contactForm":{"title":"Mr","firstName":"Jimmy","phonenumber":"12341234"}}
```

How would I use sed to surround these values with the underscore?

Comment: In Perl:   [s/"(\[^:\]+)"(?=,|}|$)/"_$1_"/g](https://regex101.com/r/MvnMhR/1)  Add whatever is expected for the ending, i.e. `(?=\s*,|\s*}|\s*$)`

Comment: `sed 's/\("[^"]*":"\)\([^"]*\)\("\)/\1_\2_\3/g' file`, or just `sed 's/:"\([^"]*\)"/:"_\1_"/g' file`

Comment: Thank you both, @WiktorStribiżew your 2nd answer is what I was looking for, do you want to answer this question and I mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
sed 's/:"\([^"]*\)"/:"_\1_"/g' file > newfile
```

The POSIX BRE pattern matches:

- `:"` - a `:"` substring
- `\([^"]*\)` - Capturing group 1: any 0 or more chars other than `"`
- `"` - a `"` char.

The RHS contains a `\1` placeholder that pastes back the value stored in capturing group #1.